# How to delete template cache varing on variables in Django

Tags: python, django, caching, signals, django-signals

In my Django template I have a block cached:

```
{% cache 300 markers_list request.user.pk request.LANGUAGE_CODE %}
    {% for marker in page_obj.object_list %}
    {{ marker }}
{% endcache %}
```

I use a signal to invalidate a cache:

```
@receiver(signal=[post_save, post_delete], sender=Marker)
def clear_cache_block(sender, request, **kwargs):
    key = make_template_fragment_key("markers_list", [request.user.pk, request.language_code])
    cache.delete(key)
```

I do not understand how to get [request.user.pk, request.language_code].

If I add request to `clear_cache_block(sender, request, **kwargs)` I get an error:

```
clear_cache_block() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know is this a good solution or there are some better ones, so I handled it with this code:

```
from django.utils.translation import get_language

@receiver(signal=[post_save, post_delete], sender=Marker)
def clear_cache_block(sender, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs["instance"].owner_id
    user_language = get_language()
    key = make_template_fragment_key("markers_list", [user, user_language])
    cache.delete(key)
```

Or one more is:

```
@receiver(signal=[post_save, post_delete], sender=Marker)
def clear_cache_block(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    user = instance.owner_id
    user_language = get_language()
    key = make_template_fragment_key("markers_list", [user, user_language])
    cache.delete(key)
```